# Determining whether $\left\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid \text{$x$ may be written with positive denominator less than $4$} \right\}$ is a well-defined set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve exercise 0.10 in Fraleigh's book, which asks whether the object $$\left\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid \text{$x$ may be written with positive denominator less than $4$} \right\}$$
is a well-defined set and, if so, to give an alternative description of it.

I believe it's a well-defined set, but I'm having some trouble figuring out exactly how to describe it. With positive denominator $1$, I get all of the integers. With positive denominator $2$, I'm going to get $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{3}{2}, - \frac{1}{2}$, etc. (odd numerators over $2$ and the integers again), with $3$ I'll get everything of the form $\frac{k}{3}$, and with $4$ there will again be some duplications.

I can't think of a concise way to describe this, but I worry I'm missing something on well-definedness. As far as I can tell, this is a perfectly fine, well-defined set and it isn't ambiguous whether a rational number is an element of it. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems unambiguously well defined to me as well. Note that you can write it as $\Bbb Z \cup \frac12\Bbb Z \cup \frac13\Bbb Z \cup\frac14\Bbb Z$, since union doesn't care if there are duplications.

Comment: For an alternative description: it is $\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid x\in\mathbb Z\lor 2x\in\mathbb Z\lor 3x\in\mathbb Z\lor 4x\in\mathbb Z\}$ or $\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid \{x,2x,3x,4x\}\cap\mathbb Z\ne\emptyset\}$.

Comment: To make it simpler, just $\frac13\mathbb Z\cup\frac14\mathbb Z$! (Why?)

Comment: @MH.Lee I think I see it. If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is even, then I'd solve $\frac{1}{4} z = x$, giving $z = 4x$. If $x$ is odd, I'd solve $\frac{1}{3} z = x$, giving $z = 3x$. It seems that this set captures all of the integers and a proper subset of the rational numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure the proper definition of well-defined of a set but I imagine it would be something along the lines: Given an arbtriray $q \in \mathbb Q$ it can be unambiguously determined whether $q$ is or is not in the set.  As all $q$ have a fractional representation as $\frac ab$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $b \in \mathbb N$ then it is clear whether the rational in lowest terms has a denominator of less than $4$. The issue is if there is *another* representative of $q$.  It's easy to prove that the fraction in "lowest terms" has the smallest possible denominator so that should be well defined.

Comment: "To make it simpler, just 13Z∪14Z! (Why?" @MH.Lee.  That is absolutely true but the issue of describing need not require describing *effeciently* and I think for the purpose of this excercise more precise and more efficient may not be desirable and the cost of more intuitive.  If this is the set of rationals whose denominators are less than $4$ then... It's the set of rationals whose denominators are 1,2, 3 or 4.

Comment: I think  most of the comments are overlooking the definition is the denominator is *less* than $4$.  Not less than or equal.  So it is the set of Integers and those with denominators of $2$ and those with denominators of $3$.

Comment: Okay... It is clear that I have made a mistake by looking only at Greg Martin's comments and missing an important point in the matter. However, I disagree with the back of your comment, and I think it is quite important to realize that it is possible to omit $\mathbb Z$ with a simple intuition, @fleablood

Comment: @MH.Lee Fair  enough.  It's a pretty open ended question and there are many ways to describe it.

Comment: There's no harm in duplicates but if you want to avoid them the trick is that $\gcd(numerator, denominator) =1$.  For $\frac k1$ that means just the set of integers.  For $\frac k2$ that means $k$ is odd.  For $\frac k3$ that means $k$ is not divisible by $3$.  (Note:  $\frac 63$ is a duplicate).  For $\frac k4$ that means $k$ is odd$.